# ¿Cómo importar una clase en Java de manera manual?

Tags: java, poo, clase, java-import

¿Cómo importo una clase de manera manual?

No cuento con un IDE de tal modo, que con **netBeans*** puedo crear mi package he importar mi clase.

Estoy trabajando con ***sublimetext3*** y he intenado realizar los siguiente:

```
import Libreria.LLFunciones; import Libreria.*; import LLFunciones;
```

pero no he tenido éxito.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

talvez no quieres utilizar netbeans, porque tendras tus motivos, un tiempo me paso lo mismo, deseaba utilizar editores mas ligeros, pero al final termine utilizando netbeans, por la robustes, asi que no dudes tanto y es preferible que uses netbeans para los problemas mas futuros te solucionara muchos problemas saludos.

Comment: lo he utilizado, pero lamentablemente para mi. mi computadora llego a su etapa final por lo cual me toco armar una que tenia entre mis cosas guardadas, y es básica, no soporta netBeans* por lo cual me toca hacer todo de manera nativa, el problema que no se como importar una clase de manera manual.

Answer (score 0):

Para tu problema lo mejor sería que utilizaras una herramienta como Maven o gradle para administrar las dependencias de tu proyecto y la compilación de el, Maven es muy ligero y es independiente del IDE o editor de texto que utilizes.

Te dejo un tutorial sobre como usar maven, si sigues con problemas y necesitas que te complemente la respuesta con un tutorial paso a paso házmelo saber.

https://www.journaldev.com/33593/creating-java-project-maven-archetypes

Otra alternativa, si no dispones de una buena PC lo más seguro es que no puedas acceder a una serie de características como son el java autocompletado ya que este último consume algo de recursos ya sea si usas Netbeans, eclipse o vs code, mi consejo sería que uses un IDE online como lo es gitpod  el cual está basado en va code y soporta varios lenguajes entre ellos java, gitpod soporta maven y gradle además autocompletado y demás caracteristicas.

Gitpod es gratis y solo necesitas un navegador y conexión a internet. https://www.gitpod.io/

Comment: Me Funciono, también quiero agregar, que tienes que anexar tu misma clase, en la misma carpeta y compilar, no es necesario importar la clase. al compilar lo detecta.